# Creating a query with a one-to-one relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two tables...a **loan** table and a **customer** table. A customer can make multiple loans but I would like to restrict the customer to one active loan at a time. They cannot create a second loan until the first loan is finished (**loan.active=false**)

I have set up my loan table like this :

```
@Entity
public class Loan implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x62B6DA99AA12AAA8L;

@Column @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Id private Integer id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Customer customer;

@Column private String dateLoaned;
@Column private String dateToReturn;
@Column private String dateOfReturn;
@Column private Boolean active=false;
```

And the customer table like this :

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x63A6DA99BC12A8A8L;

@Column @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Id private Integer id;
@Column private String firstname;
@Column private String surname;
@Column private String address;
@Column private String town;
@Column private String postcode;
@Column (unique=true) private String personalnumber;
@Column (unique=true) private String emailaddress;


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Loan loan;
```

This allows me to create a new loan with the same customer. So far so good.

I would like to make a query that allows me to find if a customer already has an active loan.

My loan repository so far is :

```
@Query("select loan_id from Loan l where l.customer.id = :customerId and l.active = true")
Boolean customerHasActiveLoan(@Param("customerId") Integer customerId);
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `spring-data-jpa` you can both have `@Query` or write a method that generates a query. There is nothing wrong to have `@Query` but because your repository method is quite simple you can use also method name only

For the example the equivalent of:

```
//Will return the active loan, if exists, or null
@Query("select l from Loan l where l.customer.id = :customerId and l.active = true")
public Loan getActiveLoad(@Param("customerId") Integer customerId)
```

could be simplified as

```
public Local findOneByCustomerIdAndActiveIsTrue(Long id)
```

Sometimes `method name` approach can generate long method name, and for this reason, if you prefer, you can use `@Query` annotation

Comment: Ok, that doesn't really add anything to what I already had but thanks anyway. I mostly wondered if this query approach was the right way to do it.

Comment: Right, that's more what I was looking for. I think I understand what's going on now. What you are describing is that you can write a simple statement that is translated as a query from the function name. Thanks!